# Coinbase iOS SDK Completion Block

Tags: ios, swift, coinbase-api

I am using Swift 4 and I am trying to use OAuth via Coinbase's SDK.

This is how I'm calling the final step to completing the OAuth:

```
    CoinbaseOAuth.finishAuthentication(for: url, clientId: Constants.CLIENT_ID, clientSecret: Constants.CLIENT_SECRET, completion: { (result : AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    } as! CoinbaseCompletionBlock)
```

When I first typed this out I did not have `as! Coinbase CompletionBlock` but Xcode complained and said I needed to add it.

When I looked at the method signature I see the completion block type:

```
+ (void)finishOAuthAuthenticationForUrl:(NSURL *)url
                               clientId:(NSString *)clientId
                           clientSecret:(NSString *)clientSecret
                             completion:(CoinbaseCompletionBlock)completion;
```

So I dig a little deeper and look at the `CoinbaseCompletionBlock` definition:

`typedef void (^CoinbaseCompletionBlock)(id response, NSError *error);`

When I try to run the code I get an unhelpful error message:
[image]

Does anyone see why this might be causing an issue?

Answer (score 0):

The cast should not be there. And you don't need the types in the completion handler parameters. This should work:

```
CoinbaseOAuth.finishAuthentication(for: url, clientId: Constants.CLIENT_ID, clientSecret: Constants.CLIENT_SECRET, completion: { (result, error) in

})
```

And you should be able to drop `completion:`

```
CoinbaseOAuth.finishAuthentication(for: url, clientId: Constants.CLIENT_ID, clientSecret: Constants.CLIENT_SECRET) { (result, error) in

}
```